# using ta.pivothigh inside a for loop in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, trading

I wanted to check if certain previous candles are pivot high or not..
to figure out the code i first tried to see if the below simple code works but it doesnt and i cant figure out why!  this code should find how many candles has passed from the last pivot high of [4,0] ( 4 candles left and 0 candles right) and lookback range is 30 candles . ... but it doesnt work properly. just sometimes it gives correct answers. could someone tell me why?

```
//@version=5
indicator("pivot")
b=0
for i=0 to 30 
    b:=i
    if high[i]==ta.pivothigh(high[i],4,0)
        break
plot(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ta.pivothigh only returns the value when current candle is actual pivothigh

So you will have to save the pivothigh in a variable eg. hi and then use it inside the loop

```
//@version=5
indicator("pivot")
var hi=0.0
hi:=ta.pivothigh(high,4,0)

var b=0
b:=0
for i=0 to 100 
    b:=i
    if high[i]==hi[i]
        break
plot(b,color=color.red)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. you answered my question ... But actually my main issue was to find out if certain previous candles were pivothigh or not . That is why i was using "for" loop (to check all past candles in the lookback range) .i still cant manage to find a way even considering the fact you mentioned about being na .. do you have any solution for that ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to use for loop to check if any lookback range candles are pivothigh or not

Comment: This works fine. Thanks. I wonder why it works this way? what is wrong with my version?